# How to re-install kubuntu after log error

Tags: linux, kubuntu

I had earlier tried to install Kubuntu 10.10 on my machine which runs Windows XP. However, the installation got aborted due to some reason and my machine restarted. Then afterwards when I tried installing Kubuntu again , it gave me an error saying that a log file "wubi" was already present. Hence now I am not able to install Kubuntu.

Can someone tell me how should solve this problem?